# How to console.log LinkedList

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm looking at a tutorial to solve how to reverse a linked list.

I want to `console.log` through the solution to see how everything works but I get the following

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
var reverseList = function(head) {
  let prevNode = null
  while (head !== null) {
    let nextNode = head.next;
    head.next = prevNode
    prevNode = head;
    head = nextNode;
  }
  return prevNode;
};

const n1 = {val: 4}
const n2 = {val: 7}
const n3 = {val: 1}
const n4 = {val: null}

n1.next = n2;
n2.next = n3;
n3.next = n4;

reverseList(n1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to detech both undefined and null situations.I wrote seperately. But you can also do as first answer just say `while(head)`

```js
var reverseList = function(head) {
  let prevNode = null
  while (head !== null && head !== undefined) {
    let nextNode = head.next;
    head.next = prevNode
    prevNode = head;
    head = nextNode;
  }
  return prevNode;
};

const n1 = {val: 4}
const n2 = {val: 7}
const n3 = {val: 1}
const n4 = {val: null}

n1.next = n2;
n2.next = n3;
n3.next = n4;
console.log(reverseList(n1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`n4` does not have a `.next` property, so when it gets asked for it it returns `undefined`. Since `undefined !== null` the loop continues and you try to access `undefined.next`, which of course fails.

Try `while(head) {...}` instead, as you're always expecting objects and objects will always be truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You should check before calling this line if head.next is not null and its not undefinned

```
let nextNode = head.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var reverseList = function(head) {
  let prevNode = null
  while (!!head) {
    let nextNode = head.next;
    head.next = prevNode
    prevNode = head;
    head = nextNode;
  }
  return prevNode;
};

const n1 = {val: 4}
const n2 = {val: 7}
const n3 = {val: 1}
const n4 = {val: null}

n1.next = n2;
n2.next = n3;
n3.next = n4;

reverseList(n1)
```